# Has anyone found a fix for "ParsedContract.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version"?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Following the truffle pet shop tutorial and ran into this error when running truffle migrate:

```
ParsedContract.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.2+commit.1df8f40c.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
contract Election {
^------^
Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
Node v11.2.0
```

when running truffle version I get:

```
Truffle v5.0.0 (core: 5.0.0)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v11.2.0
```

and in my contracts Im using:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24
```

Has anyone ran into this issue? Any help getting past this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using truffle v5, by default it will use solc v0.5.0.

But you can add a [configuration option](https://www.truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#solc) to specify solc version to use.

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.4.25"
    }
  }
};
```

IMHO the better option is to migrate your contracts to solc v0.5.0.